# Establishing if an element is on screen by framerate / requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, performance, iframe, cross-domain, requestanimationframe

I have my JS being delivered in an x-domain iframe so can't access the top window to establish element position. The other option I've read about for establishing if an element is on-screen is "Browser Optimisation", which I believe runs some frame rate tests in the iframe, and assumes that if the frame rate is slow, it's because the browser knows it's off-screen and is therefore not prioritising it.

At 60fps, the browser should try to animate at 1 frame every 16.6666666667ms for on-screen content. I've set up this fiddle with a log every time the frame rate drops below 16.6666666667fps, but there doesn't seem to be a clear difference when the box is scrolled on or off screen:

```
var lastTime = 0;
var box = document.getElementById('box');
var slowIsGt = 16.6666666667;

function loop(time) {
    var delay = time - lastTime;
    var fps = 1000/delay;

    //console.log(delay + ' ms, ' + fps);
    if(delay>slowIsGt){
        console.log('RENDERING SLOWER THAN ' + slowIsGt + ' ' +delay + ' ms, ' + fps);
    }

    updateAnimation();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    lastTime = time;
}

function updateAnimation(){
    if(box.style['text-shadow'] === '1px 1px 1px'){
        box.style['text-shadow'] = '0 0 0';     
    }else{
        box.style['text-shadow'] = '1px 1px 1px';                       
    }
}

document.getElementById('startBtn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4xhpL4cw/1/

Has anyone tried anything like this before? I can't see how I'd get a measurable result to clearly say it's on or off screen. Also this would be affected massively by the end user's computer CPU. Resources online are sparse, but this was probably most useful thing I found: http://www.contextis.com/documents/2/Browser_Timing_Attacks.pdf

Comment: Relevant bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100257

Comment: This bug seems to relate to the Page Visibility API properties, which are (in current Chrome) correctly not doing the requestAnimationFrame callbacks, but they only relate to switched tab/window minimised. I'm looking for a way to tap into the browser's own internal knowledge of what is in the viewport. Iframes that are in a top window which is active tab/not minimised will report Page Visibility stuff as visible/in-view, whether they're in the viewport or not.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that according to [Timing control for script-based animations](http://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/):

> Whenever a Document's hidden attribute ([Page Visibility]) is false and the animation frame request callback list is not empty, the user agent MUST regularly queue a task that samples all animations for that Document's top-level browsing context.

So if the iframe was considered hidden, that should work as expected. However, according to the [Page Visibility](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/#sec-document-interface) spec:

> On getting, the hidden attribute MUST return true if the Document contained by the top level browsing context (root window in the browser's viewport) [HTML5] is not visible at all.

Since the iframe is contained in a visible document, that's the top-level browsing context, so the iframe is still considered not hidden. I verified this by scrolling an iframe in/out of view and logging to console whether it was hidden.

So it seems like although it'd be awesome if animation frame events did not fire if an iframe was scrolled out of view, that's not how the specs describe its behavior.

Credit to [this Webkit bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100257) for the details.

Comment: Thanks, but I believe it's possible by looking at how the browser prioritises paining. The document.hidden prop and Page Visibility (as you say) aren't accurate because they only report page min, tab switch etc. The browser knows internally if something's in viewport and prioritises. From what info I can find, requestAnimationFrame is the key.This guy talks about the browser painting differently when in viewport: https://youtu.be/RSWhvNdjAAE?t=655 also he mentions "local connections" which I'd love to know about.